# How to list extensions installed in my Xul app?

Tags: xul, rdf

In a Xul app, is there a high-level way to list the installed extensions?

Is the "Add-ons" window available for easy use?

I'm trying to search in the firefox source, but it's a long way... if someone could give a shortcut I would be thankful... :)

Maybe something related to RDF? (not sure..)

Comment: In Gecko 1.9.1/2 you can use RDF to create a flat list of extensions of a given type. SeaMonkey does this to populate its View - Apply Theme menu. In Gecko 2 you have to use the new async callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just needed to open the url: chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul from my javascript.